# Web API 2 Custom Controller method. Routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Here is my Global.asmx

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);            
    }
}
```

Here is my WebApiConfig class.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my ApiController

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "get method";
    }

    [Route("SayHello")]
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello Jim";
    }
}
```

If I browse to `http://localhost:52072/api/hello/get` then I will receive back "get method" as expected.

If I browse to `http://localhost:52072/api/hello/SayHello` then it errors with a `404 not found`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source : [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Update route

```
public class PaymentController : ApiController {
    public string Get() {
        return "get method";
    }

    //GET api/payment/SayHello
    [HttpGet]    
    [Route("api/payment/SayHello")]
    public string SayHello() {
        return "Hello Jim";
    }
}
```

You could also use route prefix

```
[RoutePrefix("api/payment")]
public class PaymentController : ApiController {
    //GET api/payment/Get
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    public string Get() {
        return "get method";
    }
    //GET api/payment/Sayhello
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("SayHello")]
    public string SayHello() {
        return "Hello Jim";
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Now I get Error 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Your route prefix works. The other doesn't for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: My bad the tilde(~) is to override route prefixes use normal route in that situation where you are mixing convention-based and attribute routing.

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute routing match with your request url, and either you need to prefix `Get` in the method name or need to put `[HttpGet]` annpotation before the method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/payment/SayHello")]
public string SayHello()
{
   return "Hello Jim";
}
```

or rename method name and prefix `Get` before it

```
[Route("api/payment/SayHello")]
public string GetSayHello()
{
   return "Hello Jim";
}
```

Comment: No. Now I get Error 405 Method Not Allowed.